# Catching HTML<img> as videostream using C++/Qt from ESP32-CAM

Tags: html, c++, qt, esp32

**I have:** ESP32-CAM local streaming web server (192.168.1.XXX:80) - the basic example for ESP32-CAM. It generates the HTML DOM with videostream captured in `<img src="http://192.168.1.xxx:81/stream/">` tag.

**I'd like:** to get the stream via C++/Qt-framework.

**Questions are:**

1.How does generating videostream in `<img>` tag work (is this generally good practice)? Are there a lot of refrashing callbacks for each frame or something? There are no scripts nor GET requests, is it some sort of inter-protocol interaction (UDP-HTTP) ? Don't get it. Any literature/articles on the subject appriciated :)

2.How can I capture  tag using C++/Qt? I've tryed QWebSocket, but got only HTML DOM formated in string ... And even if I can get one frame (if I would hadle how to GET request an `<img>` tag), - how can I capture the stream without missing frames and economical use of resources?

Comment: Do you want to display the video in a GUI or do you want to process the video? If it is the first thing, the easiest thing is to use a QWebEngineView

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thanks for reply!
I'd like to get the sequence of frames only (for now), maybe to display it, just for debug purposes

Comment: Then use QNetworkAccessManager making a request to the url: "http://192.168.1.xxx:81/stream/"

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thank you, I will try it!

Comment: @eyllanesc, I've used QNetworkAccessManager, metohod "QNetworkReply * get(const QNetworkRequest &request)". Now I still can read only DOM and when I try to read url: "192.168.1.xxx:81/stream" - I got an empty array

Comment: Use the following code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/d0b8a232970b05f7e0f62054f6b3af09 and tell me what you get.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thank you for being involved so deeply, but as I said before - I got nothing, but Url, besides, when I get any other (http) site - I can get full html page with no problem... here is my project (I've added your error processing): https://github.com/IlaySalem/GetHtml

Comment: @eyllanesc, I've added trouble example with html code I'm trying to parse https://github.com/IlaySalem/GetHtml/commit/8f4591fc7af85ad8f7ccad6ab792cf21a004e709